# Accidentally knocked a capacitor off a laptop motherboard seemingly related to USB

Tags: capacitor, usb, motherboard

I accidentally knocked off a capacitor from my laptop motherboard (Lenovo Thinkpad S540, VIUS6 LA-A171P board). According to the circuit diagram, this capacitor (C2434) was something to do with the USB 3.0 circuit (perhaps the VBUS). See the pics attached. **The C2434 capacitor is toward the top-right of the second image**

[image]

[image]

My question is should I be worried? Everything seems to be working fine right now, but I'm worried this will come back to bite me in weeks/months from now. I don't really care if the USB port stops working or something, but don't want a more serious issue to arise.

Comment: knocking off a smoothing cap rarely causes serious problems (partially because any decent design should have other caps somewhere on the same rail), some devices might reset if the voltage drops too much, but these devices should have their own smoothing caps anyway, it's not going to make the laptop explode if that's what you're thinking (I've got an *exploded* IC on one of my usb3 ports and it's now bypassed with some 30AWG hook up wire, port works fine now, most PCs are built pretty well)

Comment: Losing a host-side decoupling capacitor could put the port outside of USB spec for host capacitance.

Comment: _should I be worried?_ If you find yourself in a position where you random knock components off of the motherboard of your laptop, yeah, you should - in general - be worried. :)

Comment: How do you have a schematic for your motherboard?

Comment: @pipe: well, I don't make a habit of it :-), but I was putting on a new antenna wire, then didn't realize it was running along a cap until I closed the lid of the laptop and it wrapped around it, argh.

Comment: @immibis I bought it for a few dollars from notebookschematics.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a smoothing capacitor. They are used to smooth out transients in current draw by USB devices plugged in to the port.

If you plug in a device that uses large peak currents - such as a Wi-Fi dongle or USB HDD - then without the smoothing capacitor the 5V rail of the USB port may drop with any spike in current. Depending on the amount at which it drops you could potentially see USB devices reset if the transient is large enough to lower the voltage below what the device can run at.

If I were you I would replace it - a 220uF 6.3V capacitor is called for by the schematic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any risk of damage occurring to the laptop itself or would damage be limited to USB devices plugged in? If I just didn't use this USB port I wouldn't risk any damage right?

Comment: I'd consider replacing it, but I don't have much soldering experience and am scared of making things worse especially if the work isn't essential. If I were to go ahead, would a fairly basic soldering iron be ok for an SMT capacitor? as long as I used rosin flux and some non-lead solder? I really know very little about how to do this, so any advice appreciated.

Comment: @fpghost It is probably not going to do any damage. At worst you may end up with corrupted data on a memory stick if the voltage drops during a memory write.

Comment: OK, thanks. IF I did decide to replace the cap, could you advise on what to buy? The markings on the old were "3D5, VLPS, 220, 6.3v". I know it's 220uF and 6.3V and surface mounted, but do I also need to replace with [VLPS series](http://www.icd-sales.com/Manufacturers/Enesol/spec-sheets/VLPS_Series.pdf) or will anything do?

Comment: For example [would this](http://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Panasonic/EEE-FK0J221P/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtZ1n0r9vR22cS6GEbW2ftoihDH7qVmEC8%3d) do the job?

Comment: @fpghost if the size of the footprint matches (check the datasheets), then yes it should be fine.

Comment: Final question, if I do solder this any tips or guides to help? Things I know so far 1) clean pads with isopropyl alcohol 2) add rosin core flux (not acid core) 3) Maybe use a solder paste instead of wire? ....I'm a total newb at this, so any tips at all appreciated.

Comment: Maybe note that you don't have to solder the new cap at the same place where the old one was. If space allows, you may of course solder in a through-hole part instead. Or, if there's another convenient spot where that USB_VCCA line is accessible just put the cap there. - Notice that the cap has a polarity. Make sure you put it in in the correct orientation, i.e. `-` of the cap toward GND.

Comment: You could also take a through-hole part and only solder its '+' pin to the SMT pad. You can bend the legs as desired (best done before soldering to not damage the pad) and connect the `-` of the cap via some wire to any GND point you can easily access. Of course, you can also wire-extend an SMD to faciliate soldering (solder two separate thin wires in two steps instead of getting one SMD soldered to two pads at the same time).

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer addresses the possible functional deficiency, there is another matter to consider. When you "knocked" that cap off, the cap pads and thus the PCB tracks might have been damaged (cracks, lifts, etc.) depending on the physical impact. In most PCB designs, the power tracks first come to capacitor pads and then to sockets. Since it is working now, there appears to be no immediate problem. But in time, that USB port may become unusable.

But no, it would not affect the rest.